# Need to access the database with dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a requirement where I need to access the database in dotnetnuke. Do we need to develop a new module for that?, or dotnetnuke provides us with built-in module.

Please help!, I'm completely new to dotnetnuke.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [Reports module](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Extensions-Forge/view/ProjectDetail/project/dnnreports.aspx) which allows you to run SQL queries and transform that data into a display, which should work if you're just displaying information from the database.

If you need to accept input, you might look at the [Form & List module](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Extensions-Forge/view/ProjectDetail/project/dnnfnl.aspx) which will let you create a form, and then list the information input to the form.

Any more complicated than that, however, and it looks like you'll probably need to create a custom module (or find a third party module from [the DotNetNuke Store](http://store.dotnetnuke.com/) which meets your needs).

Comment: What if I have a requirement of inserting and removing the record from the database?